# allocating and releasing VS. autoRelease. why and when?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, allocation, autorelease

I see that many people are allocating and releasing NSStrings.

I understand that the benefit is that the string is being released immediately and not by autoRelease.

my questions :

1. does it effective and should i always prefer allocating and releasing on autoRelease?
2. what is more expansive - allocating and releasing immediately and then allocating again **OR** allocating, using and releasing in dealloc.

will appreciate any explanation.

Thanks

shani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In most cases it does not matter. I think you should use the autorelease since it makes the code more simple and the @"string" shortcut is very elegant.
2. The basic difference is the point in time when the release happens. Like I said, in most cases it does not make any difference. If you want to control the release time more closely, then you can also do that for autorelease by rolling your own `NSAutoreleasePool` pool.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you could re-use a NSString. Reusing a NSMutableString instance might be slightly faster the recreating it but you won't see the difference. Focus on simplicity and maintainability of your code.

I think your question is wether to use [[NSString alloc] init] or [NSString string]. As long as performance is not an issue, always go with the simplest one. That would be the autoreleased version, because you don't need to release it yourself.